# Jetpack Compse Glance Widget API 33 is not resizable on API 30 works

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, glance-appwidget

I'm creating app widget with glance. And on my personal phone API 30 resizable works on emulator API 33 or 32 resizable doesn't work.

Is that emulator issue? But Google Chrome widget resizable works.

**xml/widget_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/loader"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="40dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="40dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen" />
```

**xml-v31/widget_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:previewLayout="@layout/widget_preview"
    android:targetCellWidth="3"
    android:targetCellHeight="2"
    android:description="@string/widget_description"/>
```

**glance app widget**

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpSize
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.glance.GlanceModifier
import androidx.glance.ImageProvider
import androidx.glance.LocalContext
import androidx.glance.LocalSize
import androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget
import androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidgetReceiver
import androidx.glance.appwidget.SizeMode
import androidx.glance.appwidget.cornerRadius
import androidx.glance.background
import androidx.glance.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.glance.layout.padding
import androidx.glance.state.GlanceStateDefinition
import androidx.glance.state.PreferencesGlanceStateDefinition

class MyWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {
    override var stateDefinition: GlanceStateDefinition<*> = PreferencesGlanceStateDefinition

    override val sizeMode: SizeMode = SizeMode.Responsive(
        setOf(SMALL_SQUARE, HORIZONTAL_RECTANGLE, BIG_SQUARE)
    )

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        val size = LocalSize.current
        val context = LocalContext.current
        MyContent(
            modifier = GlanceModifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(ImageProvider(R.drawable.bg_widget))
                .cornerRadius(16.dp)
                .padding(8.dp)
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val WATER_WIDGET_PREFS_KEY = "WATER_WIDGET_PREFS_KEY"

        private val SMALL_SQUARE = DpSize(100.dp, 100.dp)
        private val HORIZONTAL_RECTANGLE = DpSize(250.dp, 100.dp)
        private val BIG_SQUARE = DpSize(250.dp, 250.dp)
    }
}

class MyWidgetReceiver : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {
    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget = MyWidget ()
}
```

**AndroidMAnifest.xml**

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".ui.widget.MyWidgetReceiver"
            android:enabled="@bool/glance_appwidget_available"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
```

**API 33**
| my widget | Google Chrome widget |
| -------- | -------- |
| [image: API 33 my non resiazable] | [image: API 33 Google Chrome resizable widget] |

**API 30** on this phone I have resizable indicators and is also resizable.

[image]

Comment: I would need to double check but I believe that the xml files don't merge. Meaning that from API 31 onwards you are not defining the resize attributes. In XML is okay to have everything in the same file, even when using attributes only available in higher APIs. It will just ignore those for lower APIs

Comment: As I removed "xml-v31/widget_info.xml" and moved it in normal "xml" now is working.

but now is highlighted this:
    android:previewLayout="@layout/crypto_state_widget_preview"
    android:targetCellWidth="3"
    android:targetCellHeight="2"

warning:
Attribute previewLayout is only used in API level 31 and higher (current min is 26)

I know it's only warning but I'm annoyed. :)

Comment: You can always duplicate all the attributes and add the new ones in xml-v31. There's just no inheritance for plain XMLs. It's not like styles

Comment: Ohh nice, thanks, that's works! Can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hierarchy between files inside the XML folder. It's not like styles.

You can either duplicate all fields in xml-v31 or just add everything in the base XML and ignore the warnings of higher API.